# AWS GraphQL: Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'Input!'

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm using ReactJS and `aws-amplify` to execute graphql operations.

**CODE:**

```
import {
   API,
   graphqlOperation
} from 'aws-amplify';

import { UpdateInput } from './mutations.js';

// Call mutation
const input = { /* some values */ };
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(UpdateInput, input)).then(...);
```

GraphQL mutation definition:

```
export const UpdateInput = `mutation UpdateInput($input: Input!) {
   updateInput(input: $input) {
      id, 
      name
   }   
}`
```

GraphQL Schema:

```
input Input {
   id: ID!
   name: String
}

type Mutation {
   updateInput(input: Input!): String
}
```

However, I get an error:

> [Log] Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type
>   'Input!'

Using AWS console my mutation works and `input` is NonNull (using a debugger)

Any ideas what's causing the error?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The key was `input` in the `updateInput` mutation.

```
updateInput(input: Input!): String
         // ^^^^^ input key
```

Thus, need to specify correct key in the passed variable.

```
const variables = {
  input: someData, // key is "input" based on the mutation above
};

API.graphql(graphqlOperation(UpdateInput, variables)).then(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution helped me figure out that I don't pass 'input' to a query, and instead I just pass 'id'.