# "Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type XXX" - aws-amplify & graphql & react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm running into the error: `Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'SaveCardInput!'` when I try to run the following simple graphqlOperation:

```js
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { graphqlOperation } from "@aws-amplify/api-graphql";
import { requestApproval } from "../src/graphql/mutations";

export async function saveCardLambda(id: string) {
  try {
    const lambdaResponse = await API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(requestApproval),
      {
        input: {id}
      }
    );  
    return lambdaResponse
  } catch (error) {
    throw error; // Error: Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'SaveCardInput!'
  }
}

// ../src/graphql/mutations
export const requestApproval = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation RequestApproval($input: SaveCardInput!) {
    requestApproval(input: $input)
  }
`;

// schema.graphql
input SaveCardInput {
  id: ID!
}
```

I suspect the problem is with the `input:{id}` line, but I can't figure it out. My problem appeared to be similar to this: [AWS GraphQL: Variable 'input' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'Input!'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999721/aws-graphql-variable-input-has-coerced-null-value-for-nonnull-type-input) but the fix didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Uh. Silly error:

```js
      graphqlOperation(requestApproval),
      {
        input: {id}
      }
    );
```

Should be:

```js
      graphqlOperation(requestApproval, // << move opening bracket
        {
        input: {id}
        }
      ) // move bracket
    );
```